# Please tell me how to remove duplicates from join PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function

There was a problem with duplicates and how the percentages between the first and second records are calculated according to one scenario.
Let's say we have data for:
iteration_duration{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}
iteration_duration{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}
and they have avg, med, p90,p95 and I need to calculate how much avg differs from avg in the second entry of iteration_duration{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart} and there are many such entries of type iteration_duration{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart} in one json and all of them are in metrics.
If you output only one block at a time like js.value->'values'->>'p(90)' as p90, then there is no problem, but as soon as we add to the output the table that we added via join jss.value->'values '->>'avg' as avg then we get duplicates and incomprehensible numbers for it

There is such a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.loaddt_get_metrics2(_id integer, _id1 integer)
 RETURNS TABLE(key text, p95 numeric, med numeric, avg numeric, diffP95 numeric, diffMED numeric, diffAVG numeric)
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
select 
    js.key as  metric,
        round((js.value->'values'->>'p(95)')::numeric, 3) as p95,
        round((js.value->'values'->>'med')::numeric, 3) as med,
        round((js.value->'values'->>'avg')::numeric, 3) as avg,
--    jss.key as  metric2,
        round(100 - (((jss.value->'values'->>'p(95)')::numeric *100) / (js.value->'values'->>'p(95)')::numeric), 3) as diffP95,
        round(100 - (((jss.value->'values'->>'med')::numeric *100) / (js.value->'values'->>'med')::numeric), 3) as diffMED,
        round(100 - (((jss.value->'values'->>'avg')::numeric *100) / (js.value->'values'->>'avg')::numeric), 3) as diffAVG
from loaddt as t, loaddt as tt,
json_each(t.info->'metrics') as js 
inner join json_each(tt.info->'metrics') as jss on js.key=jss.key 
and jss.value->'values'->>'p(95)' is not null and (jss.value->'values'->>'p(95)')::float <> 0 and jss.value->'values'->>'p(95)' <> js.value->'values'->>'p(95)'
where t.buildNumber in (_id, _id1) 
ORDER  BY js.key desc;
```

And this function returns from 11 to 12 duplicates, the problem, as far as I understand, is precisely in join, but I'm not sure, and I still can't fix it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3zZC.png)

```
iteration_duration{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}    41084.711   41084.711   41084.711   -1.577  -1.577  -1.577
iteration_duration{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}    41084.711   41084.711   41084.711   -1.184  -1.184  -1.184
iteration_duration{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}    41084.711   41084.711   41084.711   0.474   0.474   0.474
iteration_duration{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}    41084.711   41084.711   41084.711   -1.582  -1.582  -1.582
iteration_duration{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}    41084.711   41084.711   41084.711   -1.393  -1.393  -1.393
iteration_duration{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}    41084.711   41084.711   41084.711   -2.231  -2.231  -2.231
iteration_duration{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}    41571.281   41571.281   41571.281   -0.388  -0.388  -0.388
iteration_duration{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}    41571.281   41571.281   41571.281   1.639   1.639   1.639
iteration_duration{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}    41571.281   41571.281   41571.281   -0.393  -0.393  -0.393
iteration_duration{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}    41571.281   41571.281   41571.281   -0.206  -0.206  -0.206
iteration_duration{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}    41571.281   41571.281   41571.281   1.170   1.170   1.170
iteration_duration{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}    41571.281   41571.281   41571.281   -1.035  -1.035  -1.035
iteration_duration{scenario:eventsDriverStop}   5.257   1.720   2.007   -2.023  1.333   0.134
iteration_duration{scenario:eventsDriverStop}   5.257   1.720   2.007   0.061   0.340   -1.068
iteration_duration{scenario:eventsDriverStop}   5.257   1.720   2.007   3.137   0.811   0.574
iteration_duration{scenario:eventsDriverStop}   5.257   1.720   2.007   -1.050  1.213   -0.221
iteration_duration{scenario:eventsDriverStop}   5.257   1.720   2.007   4.321   0.709   0.741
iteration_duration{scenario:eventsDriverStop}   5.257   1.720   2.007   -0.497  0.098   -0.408
iteration_duration{scenario:eventsDriverStop}   5.254   1.714   2.028   -0.061  -0.342  1.057
iteration_duration{scenario:eventsDriverStop}   5.254   1.714   2.028   -2.085  0.996   1.190
iteration_duration{scenario:eventsDriverStop}   5.254   1.714   2.028   3.078   0.473   1.625
```

I guess the problem is in this block:

```
        round(100 - (((jss.value->'values'->>'p(95)')::numeric *100) / (js.value->'values'->>'p(95)')::numeric), 3) as diffP95,
        round(100 - (((jss.value->'values'->>'med')::numeric *100) / (js.value->'values'->>'med')::numeric), 3) as diffMED,
        round(100 - (((jss.value->'values'->>'avg')::numeric *100) / (js.value->'values'->>'avg')::numeric), 3) as diffAVG
```

JSON structure is like this:

```
{
    "root_group": {
        "name": "",
        "path": "",
        "id": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
        "groups": [],
        "checks": [
            {
                "name": "is joint 200",
                "path": "::is joint 200",
                "id": "ae8070af06d4849b5a73c0ea09c2238e",
                "passes": 12122,
                "fails": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "is status 200 find-all",
                "path": "::is status 200 find-all",
                "id": "bae23285599010636d5dcbc6311a79b6",
                "passes": 73852,
                "fails": 0
            },
            {
                "passes": 30874,
                "fails": 3395,
                "name": "is status 200 conditional",
                "path": "::is status 200 conditional",
                "id": "8f2e67a51bef6111123e1aa04f006a1c"
            }
        ]
    },
    "options": {
        "summaryTrendStats": [
            "avg",
            "min",
            "med",
            "max",
            "p(90)",
            "p(95)"
        ],
        "summaryTimeUnit": "",
        "noColor": false
    },
    "state": {
        "isStdOutTTY": false,
        "isStdErrTTY": false,
        "testRunDurationMs": 345617.874234
    },
    "metrics": {
        "data_received": {
            "contains": "data",
            "values": {
                "count": 106316067,
                "rate": 307611.59918488155
            },
            "type": "counter"
        },
        "http_req_waiting{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "avg": 0,
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "p(90)": 0,
                "p(95)": 0
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "p(95)<=2": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 3": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=2": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_blocked{scenario:find}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "min": 0.001723,
                "med": 0.004228,
                "max": 9.42929,
                "p(90)": 0.005511,
                "p(95)": 0.006082,
                "avg": 0.00487203336402536
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_duration{scenario:eventsDriverStop}": {
            "thresholds": {
                "p(95)<=8": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 4": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 4": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=7": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            },
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "p(90)": 0,
                "p(95)": 0,
                "avg": 0
            }
        },
        "http_req_waiting{scenario:con}": {
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "med": 0.936649,
                "max": 99.55948,
                "p(90)": 2.4427536,
                "p(95)": 4.682848199999995,
                "avg": 1.5082012875777009,
                "min": 0.541066
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 3": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=4": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=5.8": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            },
            "type": "trend"
        },
        "http_req_receiving{scenario:find}": {
            "values": {
                "max": 15.097094,
                "p(90)": 0.066625,
                "p(95)": 0.08054044999999994,
                "avg": 0.05262911127660761,
                "min": 0.013265,
                "med": 0.046247
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            },
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time"
        },
        "iterations{scenario:eventsDriverStop}": {
            "values": {
                "count": 1201,
                "rate": 3.4749360190406846
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "count>0": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            },
            "type": "counter",
            "contains": "default"
        },
        "vus_max": {
            "type": "gauge",
            "contains": "default",
            "values": {
                "value": 249,
                "min": 114,
                "max": 249
            }
        },
        "dropped_iterations": {
            "type": "counter",
            "contains": "default",
            "values": {
                "count": 26803,
                "rate": 77.55096596032263
            }
        },
        "http_req_duration{scenario:find}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "avg": 1.3326389626144177,
                "min": 0.446288,
                "med": 0.7976185,
                "max": 84.594877,
                "p(90)": 2.3167139000000017,
                "p(95)": 3.87368795
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "p(95)<=5": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 5": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 3": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=3.5": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_sending{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "max": 0,
                "p(90)": 0,
                "p(95)": 0,
                "avg": 0,
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "iteration_duration{scenario:con}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "p(95)": 612.0240284,
                "avg": 603.5558696238289,
                "min": 15.970423,
                "med": 607.863974,
                "max": 657.394861,
                "p(90)": 610.6949792
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 610": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 610": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=615": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=620": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "checks": {
            "type": "rate",
            "contains": "default",
            "values": {
                "rate": 0.9717655081792703,
                "passes": 116848,
                "fails": 3395
            }
        },
        "http_req_sending": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "med": 0.022442,
                "max": 3.47231,
                "p(90)": 0.030297,
                "p(95)": 0.032682,
                "avg": 0.02284295450878623,
                "min": 0.006382
            }
        },
        "http_req_receiving{scenario:prePubEventsDriverStart}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "p(95)": 0,
                "avg": 0,
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "p(90)": 0
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_sending{scenario:con}": {
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "avg": 0.02357408380752288,
                "min": 0.008426,
                "med": 0.023204,
                "max": 0.356089,
                "p(90)": 0.031048,
                "p(95)": 0.033433
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "med <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=1": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 1": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            },
            "type": "trend"
        },
        "iteration_duration{scenario:eventsDriverStop}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "avg": 1.9972035187343873,
                "min": 1.141805,
                "med": 1.685224,
                "max": 16.105638,
                "p(90)": 2.205132,
                "p(95)": 5.332459
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "p(95)<=7": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 3": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 3": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(90)<=3": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_duration{scenario:eventsDriverStart}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "min": 0,
                "med": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "p(90)": 0,
                "p(95)": 0,
                "avg": 0
            },
            "thresholds": {
                "p(90)<=7": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "p(95)<=8": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "avg <= 4": {
                    "ok": true
                },
                "med <= 4": {
                    "ok": true
                }
            }
        },
        "http_req_duration{expected_response:true}": {
            "type": "trend",
            "contains": "time",
            "values": {
                "max": 99.649419,
                "p(90)": 2.3154703000000003,
                "p(95)": 3.958521399999999,
                "avg": 1.3774202878354742,
                "min": 0.446288,
                "med": 0.848834
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using GROUP BY?

Comment: yes, didn't help..
The same problem is why where do diffs go. Different data is displayed in duplicates, although the information is the same there...

Comment: Are not you making an implicit CROSS JOIN between `t` and `tt` ?

Comment: Well, I have problems with join on one table, can you tell me how it should be?

Comment: I would bet your problem lies somewhere in the `JOIN`s. When you write `FROM loaddt t, loaddt tt, json_each(t.info->'metrics') js`. You're performing 3 `CROSS JOINS`. Not only is that extremely demanding on a table with any significant size, that's likely where your dupes are coming from. Looking into it further.

Comment: And how then to do a join on one table by json field if the option with `loaddt t, loaddt tt, json_each(t.info->'metrics') js` is not suitable?